# Laravel/PHP Unit: Run a mock only when it's called a second time in a test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm testing code that runs a for loop. It looks something like this:

```
// Class: API
public function checkAPIOnEachModel($models) {

    foreach ($models as $model) {
        return (new API)->checkAPIOnEachModel($model);
    }

}
```

In the test, I want to see what gets returned when the API fails on the second iteration but succeeds on the first.

## Test

```
public function testAPICheck()
{
    $mock = $this->mock(API::class);

    $mock->shouldReceive('checkAPIOnEachModel')->andReturn(...)
}
```

In the second line, the $mock is absolutely returning the code in the ellipses on every iteration.

Is there a way I can make it in my test so that on the first iteration, the mock returns one result, and on the second iteration, it returns a different result?

Comment: if you pass multiple arguments to `andReturn` it should do that

Comment: As @apokryfos mentioned, you can achieve what you want by just adding another argument/paratemer to the `andReturn`. Check the [documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html#declaring-return-value-expectations) (second code block)